# How to make a NSView get focus/first responder immediately to accept a mouseDown event?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nswindow

I have an app with 2 separate NSWindow loaded.

Each window has one small table with two items in it.

Here's the problem i cant seem to solve -->

If window #1 is active/focused, i can click on the individual rows in the table normally. But if i want to click the rows in the table within window #2, I have to click the table twice. The first click to get Window #2 in active/focused, and finally the second click to actually select the row.

How can i get to select the rows in the NSTableViews in only one click (regardless if their windows are in focus or not) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I sub-classed the NSTableView.

```
-(BOOL)acceptsFirstMouse:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
   return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Create an IBOutlet of your NSTableView as:

```
IBOutlet NSTableView* yourTable;
```

Bind it to your table.

Then use:

```
[window2 makeFirstResponder: yourTable];
```

Comment: It worked for my textView. Hope it does for you too.

Comment: Did you have 2 separate windows? Youre saying you only have to click on the table view rows once?

Comment: Yes i have two separate windows, and a NSTextView in one. NSTextView get focus on 2 clicks if i don't use the above method. But after making it first responder, it gets focus on 1 click.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when your first window is active as it is first responder so obviously your tableview will be the next responder of window1 until you select it. But for second window your first responder will be window2. So you have to double click on the table twice because first responder is setting to  window2 and it is setting to table 2 for making next responder. If you want to do single click and select table of window2 then you can do through binding or programmatically as well.

Comment: [[self window] setInitialFirstResponder:(NSView *)tableView2];
            [[self window] makeFirstResponder:(NSView *)tableView2];Try like this

Comment: Have you tried this code? Where exactly do you place it? Setting the first responder doesnt seem to be working.. When i still have to click on the table row twice and not once..

Comment: You have to place this when you launch your second window